# Совместимы ли ассеты Unity 2018/17 с Unity 2019.2.15f1?

Tags: unity3d

Хочу научится геймдеву, но многого пока не знаю, поэтому надеюсь на ваше понимание. Меня интересует вопрос о совместимости с ассетами в UNity 2019.2.15f1 со старыми версиями (2018 или 2017). Совместимы ли эти ассеты с новой версией этого движка?

Comment: попробуй совместить ._.

Comment: А не правильнее ли это спросить у самих разработчиков?

Comment: Можно попробовать. Спасибо

Comment: Ассеты - это понятие растяжимое. Обычно имеет смысл делать все ассеты экспортируемыми и потенциально конвертируемыми в формат других редакторов (в т.ч. разных версий одного и того же редактора) и в формат для релизного игрового движка.

Comment: Импортировал стандартный ассеты и "поигрался" в Unity. Вроде все работает. Спасибо за ваши ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждого ассета есть минимальная версия, которая рекомендуется для использования. Версию можно посмотреть на странице вот тут[image: введите сюда описание изображения]